# Usar nodemcu para enviar datos desde sensor de pulso

Tags: firebase, arduino

Estoy intentando enviar los datos recogidos desde un sensor de pulso [PulseSensor](http://pulsesensor.com/), pero el codigo esta dirigido a la placa Arduino y no a placa NodeMCU, este ejemplo [Ejemplo NodeMCU](https://www.hackster.io/kuncono/online-heart-rate-monitor-using-nodemcu-and-cayenne-e332ee)(en este caso usaria Firebase) tampoco sirvio, ya que hay error al compilar en:

```
interruptSetup(); // sets up to read Pulse Sensor signal every 2mS
```

Según vi es por el mismo motivo el codigo es para Arduino y no para MCU, me podrian indicar alguna alternativa para este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucion: Cambiar el interrupt.ino del proyecto original del sensor https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensor_Amped_Arduino
por el interrupt de este proyecto https://github.com/EnvironmentMonitor/Pulse-Sensor-ESP8266-ADC0, segun seria porque el arduino si trabaja con timers pero el nodemcu no.